# Why onBeforeAction triggered whereas action is not?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

during my last meteor meetup i presented IronRouter. I created a project https://github.com/MeteorLyon/tutorial-ironrouter that shows how to manage pages and hooks.
When i use subscriptions hook, it's ok, onBeforeAction and onAfterAction are called when it should be before and after action method.
But when i use waiton hook, onBeforeAction is called only when subscriptions are ready (which seems normal) but onAfterAction is called as data/onRun/onRerun hooks. I expected onAfterAction to be called only if action method is ran.

```
Router.route('/waiton', {
 waitOn: function() {
     console.info('%c waitOn - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
     return Meteor.subscribe('router-citations-for-waiton', Session.get('clickCount'), function() {console.warn('%c data loaded %s %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());});
 },
onRun: function () {
    console.info('%c onRun - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
    this.next();
},
onRerun: function () {
    console.info('%c onRerun - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
      this.next();
},
onBeforeAction: function () {
    console.info('%c onBeforeAction - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
    this.next();
},
onAfterAction: function () {
    console.info('%c onAfterAction - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
},
onStop: function () {
    console.info('%c onStop - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
},
data: function() {
    console.info('%c data - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
    return Characters.find();
},
action: function() {
    console.info('%c action - citations: %s, characters: %s', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', Citations.find().count(), Characters.find().count());
    this.render('waiton');
    this.render('marvel_footer', {to: 'footer'});
}
});
```

When you go to this url (http://tuto-router.meteor.com/waiton) you will see that behavior.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: no answers on this question ?